# Connect with the Filezilla Server Software to a FTP Server

Tags: networking, ftp

I'm running a FTP Server on my Android device, there I want to change the options, but this is very uncomfortable, and I want to have a more overviewed Log, so I tried to connect with the FileZilla Server to this Android FTP Server, but it couldn't connect.

It showed me this error:

> Protocol error: Unknown protocol identifier (0x50 0x50 0x48). Most likely connected to the wrong port.

I used the Standart Port from FileZilla (14147) and the port which I have choosen on my Android FTP Server.

Comment: An FTP server on your Android, now isn't that something. In any case, the 14147 is the default admin interface port for FileZilla server from what I read. Otherwise, from your server access the interface via 127.0.0.1 although I've never done this from an Android. This is what I read here: [FileZilla Wiki](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/FAQ)`For the server port, you have to enter the same port number you did specify during installation for the admin port.`

Comment: What are you using on Android to run FTP server? Show us the settings you're using for FTP server.